# Group with exactly two subgroups

Tags: group-theory

Can someone give me an example of a group which has exactly $2$ proper, non-trivial subgroups?

I appreciate that there is no context with this question but there's no really much else I can say.

Comment: The cyclic groups of order $p$ a prime have this property, and in fact are the only ones.

Comment: With the new constraint, $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ where $n$ has exctly two proper divisors. For instance $n= p^3$ with $p$ prime.

Comment: The suggestions that people are giving are the simple groups which have do not have any proper, nontrivial normal subgroups.  This is not what the question is asking.

Comment: Adding to @CaptainLama 's response, you can also use $\mathbb{Z}/pq\mathbb{Z}$ where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is meant that the group has to have exactly two non triavial soubgroups (the case with only trivial soubgrops was already mentioned in the comments) one example is $(\mathbb Z_6,+)$. The non trivial soubgroups are
$$ H_1=\{0,2,4\},\qquad H_2=\{0,3\}
$$
In fact, a non trivial soubgroup $H$ cannot contain 1 nor 5 $(5+5+5+5+5=1)$. Moreover $H$ cannot contain both 2 and 3, or both 4 and 3.